# Documentum xCP 2.0 Designer Customization

Tags: documentum, xcp2.x

Can we add plugins in xCP designer like we can add in Eclipse?

We need to have SVN plugin, so that we can do code versioning.

Actually the problem is in our project multiple people need to work on same object. So can we do it in xCP?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Till now I hv not tried..

Comment: Is it possible or feasible..?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself (and I'm not at work right now). But xCP Designer is Eclipse based, so it might work. However SVN plugins like Subversive are designed to work with the views available in the standard perspectives of Eclipse. If you can't hack it, what about using SVN outside of it, e.g. TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Yeah u r write tortise also a good option .. But if things can get configure in Eclipse it would be easier for compare, conflicts.. single file update...

Comment: Thanks for ur response.. I will try and post here.. Or let other comment on it ...

Comment: I am looking into it these days, I hope I'll have answer with start of the next week.

Comment: Thanks Miki ..  Please post ........

Comment: Also I did ask technical presales within EMC is it possible to work on the same project with more developers using their own offline xCPDesigners. I don't expect positive answer but this really is xCP 2.X bottleneck from my point of view. We'll see the answers

Answer (score 1):

Googling around I found an interesting post from Chris Campbell -> [Tips for Using Source Control in xCP 2.0](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-26660) and also Kyle Pettit writing basically the same thing in his [post](https://community.emc.com/message/727662#727662). I don't doubt that you can integrate source control plugin to the xCPDesigner but since my team is used to Git and most of us using standalone clients we'll walk that way. 
I can't share any experience yet, but I'll try to update this post in the future.

From xCPDesigner Help Manual:

**Include** following files/folders:

- .settings/
- Artifacts/
- content/
- lib/
- src/
- .classpath
- .project
- build.properties
- pom.xml

**Ignore** following files/folders:

- configuration/
- gen/
- META-INF/
- target/
- .index
- .generatedresources
- runapp.log

To work with an application that another developer has added to the source control repository:

- Check out the application from the source control repository to the checkout directory on your file system.
- Import the application into your xCP Designer environment. Do not select the option to import a copy of the application.
- After you update shared resources, check them into the source control repository.
- To get changes that were checked in by other developers, use your source control client to synchronize your local file system with the changes from the source control repository and then click Refresh on the xCP Designer toolbar to pick up the latest changes.

Refer to the documentation for your source control system for more information on setting up a source
control system and using the source control client to complete source control actions.